# NSTask File Path Converting Into ShellPath?

Tags: objective-c, macos, shell, osx-mountain-lion, nstask

I have a **Mac** (not iOS) application.  I want to run a shell command 'find' after the user selects a folder with **NSOpenPanel**.  The following is what I have.

```
NSString *path = [url path];
NSString *folderName = [path lastPathComponent];

NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/find"];
NSMutableString *command = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:path];
[command appendString:@" -name '._*' -type f "];
NSArray* args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"commit",command,nil];
[task setArguments:args];
NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];
[task launch];
NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",output);
```

It's my first time running a shell command with a Mac application that is developed with Objective-C.  I suppose that I'm on the right track.  Anyway, when I select a folder, I get the following debugger output message.

- find: commit: No such file or directory
- find: find: /Volumes/SDHC 16 GB/More -name '._*' -type f : No such file or directory

I suppose that the shell command cannot read this sort of file paths.  Do I need to convert it into a shell path or whatever it understand?  If so, how?

Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

I got it.

```
NSString *path = [url path];
NSString *folderName = [path lastPathComponent];

NSTask *task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[task setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/find"];
NSMutableString *command = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
[command appendString:@" -name '._*' -type f"];
NSArray* args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:path,command,nil];
[task setArguments:args];
NSPipe *pipe;
pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
[task setStandardOutput: pipe];
[task launch];
NSFileHandle *file;
file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
NSData *data;
data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];
NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",output);
```